# Use double click to bring window to front instead of single, in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I often like to drag images from my browser to folder, but currently this requires me to display the browser and explorer window side by side. I would like to have my browser on fullscreen and drag it to my explorer window, but currently single clicking any part of browser would bring the browser window to the front and hide the explorer window. I want to change it so that a window does not come up to front unless double clicked. This would make it possible to work with a window in the background without hiding the one in foreground.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but as a workaround, you could drag the image to the Explorer's taskbar button first. This will bring Explorer to the foreground again, allowing you to drag the image to it. Not ideal, I know.